# creating a blank version/instance of a page on the spot

Tags: php, html, instance

Sorry for the noob question. I have this simple page here- it asks the user to fill those blank spaces, it saves on a database and if the user enters to the that page again the saved data pops up (it can also be changed and stuff)

my problem is that is the only option an user has to only fill up this one page, i need them to fill up multiple of these with different data

what would i need to do if i wanted to creating more blank versions of that page on the spot (to push a button or something), to bring up an entirely fresh/blank version or instance of this same page so that different data could be saved on a different entry on the database?

[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMudk.png)

[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sRrv.png)

Comment: don't waste our time with images.  They are really not helpful.  First, learn how to ask a question. second, show your code

Comment: Its not really a matter of code, since its merely a page with forms that works well already. Its more of a matter that i dont know how to proceed from there. Its a page with forms, the data from said forms goes into a database, then i use php echo isset so that the user can see said data again in the forms. But what i want to know is how to let the user have several of the same page with forms, just creating on the spot instead of me making copies before hand

Comment: The data is probably stored in the database under some unique record ID. So make your script take that as a parameter - `foo.php?id=123`. Then you can read the data for that record from the database, if such an ID is passed to the script. And you can read all existing records (for the current user, or all of them), to create a list of links to those pages dynamically.

Comment: Put that record ID into a hidden form field, so that when this gets submitted, you know which record to update. If a "fresh" form gets submitted, then that particular parameter won't exist, so you know in that case you need to INSERT a new record, instead of UPDATE-ing an existing one.